# jQuery function doesn't get called / loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ckeditor

I give up!  I have an ASP.NET MVC application and for some reason my jQuery function doesn't get called when I click on the dropdown control.  I am supposedly loading the function at the bottom of my page by including the script file.  My hunch is that it's not getting loaded.  I have another program very similar and it the code works fine.

### **Editor.cshtml**

```
@model MyProgram.Models.WebPages

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Editor";
}

<script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="~/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="cl-mcont">
        <div class="row dash-cols">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="block-flat">
                    <div class="content">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitForm", "Edit", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="DropID" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a Page<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">HOME PAGE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">BEER PAGE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">SPIRITS PAGE</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">WINE PAGE</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WebPageText, new { @id = "editor1" })

                            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',
        {
            // removePlugins: 'toolbar,elementspath',
            allowedContent: true,
            resize_enabled: true,
            // readOnly: true
            height: '1000px'
        });
</script>

<script src="~/Scripts/Custom/Editor.js"></script>
```

### **Editor.js**

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText + ' <span class="caret"></span>');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Edit/DropdownChanged',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: selText }),
        success: function (sText) {
            //alert("Updated Text=" + sText);
            var ckEditor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
            ckEditor.setData(sText);
            ckEditor.updateElement();
            //success: function (sText) {
            //if (valid) {
            //  //show that id is valid
            //  alert("true");
            //} else {
            //  //show that id is not valid
            //  alert("false");
            //}
        }
    });
});
```

Many Thanks
Peter

Comment: Look at the source of the web page (Ctrl+U), find the `<script>` and click the `src`. Do you see your script?

Comment: While running the application in your web browser you can also check if the script has loading by looking at the sources tab of your developer console (in the browser). My hunch is that you're using partials as I've run into a similar issue with partials in MVC.

Comment: is `Editor.js` code loaded before or after the *HTML* you posted - there's a reference to ckeditor.js but not editor.js in your post - it could simply be that the `click` handler is bound before the `.dropdown-menu li a` items exist - look into Event delegation if that is the case - e.g. `$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li a", function () { ....})`

Comment: I pressed Ctrl+U and I found my src and clicked on it and saw my code that in the Editor.js file.

Comment: I clicked on the sources tab and it just shows the Editor.cshtml file.  I don't see the Editor.js file.

Comment: The Editor.js file is included at the end of the file Editor.cshtml

Comment: How do I check the Event delegation?

Comment: Is the jquery code you have for click of dropdown within `document.ready`? If not, then change your Editor.js so that click event handler is within document.ready event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I figured it out!  I just had to move one statement, @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) to the bottom in the _Layout.cshtml file

 - <!-- Scripts -->
          <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
          ================================================== -->
          <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster --> 

<!--  IT WAS ORIGINALLY HERE: @RenderSection("scripts", required: false) -->

          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
          <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="~/Scripts/Template/theme.js"></script>

          <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Template/index-slider.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Template/flexslider.js"></script>

<!-- NOW ITS AT THE BOTTOM -->
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```